# Counting All articles using withCount()

Tags: php, laravel

I am using withCount() to count the number of articles in a category, everything works well.

The question is how to count and display the number of articles for **All** categories?

**Controller**

```
$categories = BlogCategory::withCount('articles')->get();
```

**blade.php**

```
<div class="blog-filter">
   <div class="blog-filter__item active" data-filter="all">All</div>
   @foreach($categories as $category)
   <div class="blog-filter__item" data-filter=".category_{{$category->id}}" value="{{ $category->title }} ({{ $category->articles_count }})">{{ $category->title }} ({{ $category->articles_count }})</div>
   @endforeach
</div>
```

`({{ $category->articles_count }})` responsible for counting articles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [count](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_count) method:

```
$allArticlesCount=Article::query()->count();
```

and do not forget to send it to your view as well.

a better approach is to get the count directly form the result you already got from db like @Apuv Bhavsar in his comment:

```
$allArticlesCount = $categories->sum('articles_count');
```

unless you have some conditions to apply this approach reduce the trips count to DB.

Comment: Or `Article::count()`; `::query()` is generally not needed, it's implied for queries starting with `Model::`

Comment: @TimLewis, you are right, it's simply I 'm using phpstorm , without query() autocomlete will be lost, so I use to write it

Comment: Oh is that the reason. Is this plugin available for PHPStorm: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper? I know it works for VSCode to allow autocomplete/code suggestions/etc, might help you too 

Comment: so how to bring it to php.blade later, sorry, it's just that I don't really know much about the front yet

Comment: and, sorry, I understood, thanks for the help, guys

Comment: @TimLewis thanks, it's a lovely package. I install it, it works well.

Comment: Why need another query?? you can do `$categories->sum('articles_count')`. you get the  total count from your category data.

Comment: @ApurvBhavsar thanks, I missed that, I included your comment into the answer